# Is explicitly explaining the case where the Turing Machine loops forever essential to proving reducibility?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, turing-recognizable

I am asking this in the context of the following question:

> Let *N* be a non-deterministic Turing Machine. We say that N faces a dilemma if at some point in its working, it encounters a situation where the finite control is in the state *p*, the head scans the tape *a*, and $\delta (p, a)$ offers multiple (two or more) possibilities, where *p* is neither the accept state nor the reject state. Consider the following language
> $$
> \text{DILLEMA}_{ALL} = \{\langle N\rangle| N \text{ is a NTM which faces a dilemma at least once on each input}\}
> $$
> Prove that $\text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$ is not recursively enumerable

Here is how I have attempted this problem

To prove that $\text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$ is not recursively enumerable, we prove that $\bar{A}_{TM} \le_m \text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$.

Here is how we construct the proof for reducibility.

For any input $\langle M, w\rangle$ we have to return an output $N$ for our reducibility function.

1. Construct a deterministic Turing machine N which gets an input $x$ and run $M$ on $w$.
2. If $M$ accepts, accept $x$ ie. $L(N) = \Sigma^*$
3. If $M$ rejects, take any state $q$ in the Turing machine $N$ which is not accept or reject state and copy the succeeding computational graph from this state. Rename the copied states to say $q_1$ and $q_2$ and make a non-deterministic transition from $q$ to $q_1$ and $q_2$.
4. Output $\langle N \rangle$.

Proof of correctness:

1. When $w \not \in L(M) \Leftrightarrow  \langle N \rangle \in \text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$
2. When $w \in L(M) \Leftrightarrow \langle N \rangle \not \in \text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$

Thus it has been proven that $\bar{A}_{TM} \le_m \text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$ and hence $\text{DILLEMA}_{ALL}$ is not recursively enumerable.

What I have essentially done is to introduce non-determinism in a deterministic turing machine by adding a compatible transition which doesn't affect the behaviour of the machine other than making it non-deterministic.

My professor however disagrees with my proof, and claims that I did not include the case where the turing machine neither rejects nor accepts ie. loops forever in my proof of correctness for reducibility. I believe that the case is implicit since if $M$ loops forever then $N$ is obviously not giving any output ie. it is also looping forever.

Could anyone please validate my proof or explain my professor's criticisms in more detail since I was not able to understand his reasoning? I couldn't find any mention of explicitly writing the looping case even for non recursively enumerable languages in textbooks or anywhere else.

Comment: You styled the problem and prompt for proof as a block quote. Please provide [who created both and where it was published first](/help/referencing).

Comment: @greybeard I don't understand what you mean by this. The question was set by my professor for the term examination and the solution was created by me. I want to know what is wrong with my proof. I used a block quote to highlight the problem and distinguish it from my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not only your professor is correct, but also the reduction is not well-written. Specifically, you did one of the following (and both are wrong):

- The reduction simulates the run of $M$ on $w$, and then decides which $N$ to output: this cannot be done as the machine that computes the reduction may not halt.
- The reduction always halts and outputs a description of a machine $N$ that operates as follows. On input $x$ for $N$, $N$ neglects $x$ and simulates the run of $M$ on $w$. Then, depending on what happens during the simulation, you change the definition of $N$ on the fly. This is not well-defined, as the state-space of $N$ depends on how it behaves on its input $x$ -- you see now that you have a circular definition. You should define the nondeterministic state q in the machine $N$, regardless of what happens in the simulation of $M$ on $w$, meaning the nondeterministic state is always defined in $N$, and the question is whether it is not reached on some inputs only when $M$ accepts $w$.

Here is how to do it properly, and how to fix the problem of non-halting:

**The reduction:** on input $\langle M, w\rangle$, the reduction outputs $\langle N\rangle$, where $N$ is a nondeterministic machine that operates as follows.
$N$ has a single nondeterministic state $q_{N}$ from which it guesses to move to $q_{rej}$ or move to $q_{acc}$: $\delta(q_{N}, \gamma) = \{ \langle q_{acc}, \gamma, R \rangle, \langle q_{rej}, \gamma, R \rangle \}$, forall $\gamma \in \Gamma$. Then, on input $x$, $N$ computes $|x|$ and simulates the run of $M$ on $w$ for $|x|$ steps, if during the simulation $M$ did not accept $w$, then $N$ moves to the state $q_{N}$. Otherwise, if during the simulation $M$ accepted $w$, then $N$ moves to $q_{reject}$.

Clearly, for all $x$, $N$ faces a dilemma when it runs on $x$ only if it reaches the state $q_{N}$, which happens only when $M$ does not accept $w$ within $|x|$ steps.

**For the correctness:** if $\langle M, w\rangle \in \overline{A_{TM}}$, then $M$ does not accept $w$, in particular, $M$ does not accept $w$ within $|x|$ steps for all $x$. Hence, for all $x$, the run of $N$ on $x$ reaches $q_{N}$, and thus $\langle N\rangle\in DILEMMA_{ALL}$. Conversely, if $\langle M, w\rangle\in A_{TM}$, then $M$ accepts $w$ after $t$ steps. Then for all $x$ with $|x|\geq t$, $N$ moves to $q_{rej}$ and never visits $q_{N}$, and so $\langle N\rangle \notin DILEMMA_{ALL}$.

**Notes:**

1- If we allow the simulation to not halt, then on input $x$, $N$ does not accept or reject, and we do not know whether it will accept in the future or not halt. Thus, it never reaches a dilemma, but we want it to reach a dilemma in this case -- for this reason we bound the number of steps when we simulate.

2- The main thing is whether we visit $q_{N}$ or not. The fact that we sometimes accept or reject in some cases is not important.

Comment: > This cannot be done as the machine that computes the reduction may not halt.

Yes in that case there is no N given as output either. It will only decide if M halts.